# Find a $3\times 5$ system for which the given vectors are a solution

Tags: linear-algebra

I have two vectors
$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 \\
        1 \\
        -1 \\
        1 \\
        1 \\
        \end{bmatrix},
        \begin{bmatrix}
        -1 \\
        0 \\
        1 \\
        0 \\
        -1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
and want to find a  $3\times 5$  system of linear equations for which these vectors are a solution. In general, I am aware of the standard approach which would be to write down a  $3\times 5$  system with $a_{ij}$ as parameters, use the two vectors as its solutions and try to find the parameters. This is tedious as I end up with a  $6\times 15$  system. The system itself is not complicated but the size of it makes me suspect there is a much quicker way to do this. Any suggestions? In particular, I haven't covered the dot product, nullspace or kernels so far so using any of them would be a stretch.

Answer (score 1):

It's immediate just from looking at your vectors that both of them satisfy $x_1+x_3=0$. So you can take
$$ \begin{bmatrix}1&0&1&0&0 \\ 1&0&1&0&0 \\ 1&0&1&0&0\end{bmatrix} X = 0 $$

---

If you have an unstated requirement that you want the *only* solutions to your equation to be the **span** of the two given vectors (it can't possibly be those two vectors *alone*), then you need three linearly independent equations that both vectors satisfy. Again, just from looking at the vectors we can take
$$ \begin{bmatrix}1&0&1&0&0 \\ 0&0&1&0&1 \\ 0&1&0&-1&0\end{bmatrix} X = 0 $$
or even
$$ \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0&-1 \\ 0&1&0&-1&0 \\ 0&0&1&0&1\end{bmatrix} X = 0 $$
where it is particularly easy to see that the equations are independent.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just use guesswork.

My first attmpt would be a homogeneous system of equations: since we only have to find 3, and we have 5 different parameters, we definitely have enough.

I'll refer to vector elements as $[a, b, c, d, e]^T$.

First off, notice that both vectors satisfy $a+c=0$, so that can definitely be our first equation.
Then, similarly, the both satisfy $c+e=0$, so that's the next.

Finally, they satisfy $b-d=0$, which we can use as our third equation.

Overall, the resulting system can be written as:

$$\left[ \begin{matrix} 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & -1 & 0
\end{matrix} \right]
\left[ \begin{matrix} a\\ b\\c\\d\\e\end{matrix} \right] = 
\left[ \begin{matrix} 0\\ 0\\0\end{matrix} \right]$$

Comment: Indeed. That's what I get for copy-pasting my own code

Answer (score 0):

Note that the sum of the two vectors is
$$\begin{bmatrix}
        0 \\
        1 \\
        0 \\
        1 \\
        0 \\
        \end{bmatrix},
$$
So you can consider the equivalent couple
$$\begin{bmatrix}
        0 \\
        1 \\
        0 \\
        1 \\
        0 \\
        \end{bmatrix},
        \begin{bmatrix}
        -1 \\
        0 \\
        1 \\
        0 \\
        -1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}.$$
    Then you can take
$$\begin{bmatrix}a_1&b_1&2a_1&-b_1&a_1 \\ a_2&b_2&2a_2&-b_2&a_2 \\ a_3&b_3&2a_3&-b_3&a_3\end{bmatrix} X = 0$$
with $a_i,b_i\in\mathbb{R}$. For example
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&2&0&1 \\ 0&1&0&-1&0 \\ 0&0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix} X = 0.$$